# big difference size and size on disk

Tags: hard-drive

I have storage problem on my vps server.

We are transferring data from old vps server to new vps server.

On old vps server I want to transfer F partition with all directories inside.

On multiple directories I have large difference between size and size on disk:

Example of one:
Size: 137GB
Size on disk: 2,23 GB

When I want to copy whole directory to new server the directory has a size 137 GB but on old server this directory use 2,23 GB of space.

Does anybody know what I must enable on new server that directory size will be same?

I have already checked the old server. The old server is not using ntfs compressing and cluster size on both servers are same.

Print screen one of directory:
[size and size in disk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnOHS.png)

Thank you for your answers

Comment: What windows version is this? Newer versions support deduplication.

Comment: Would you have sparse files on your old system?   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365564(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: To check if deduplication is active and has any effect on the old server you can use `Get-DedupStatus` in powershell.

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably caused by the deduplication option. Deduplication removes shared data from the files, so the "size on disk" will only show the non-deduplicated fragments.

If you copy this volume to another one that's not large enough to hold data without deduplication you either need to use a tool that retains deduplication or you need to enqueue an optimize job in between copy batches (`dedupcli enqueue /opt /vol X:`).